# how to create session in javascript and access it in controller mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, session, controller

I have an mvc project. i want to create a session in javascript, and be able to access it in the controller of the page.
i've tried different options, but none worked for me...
one of the things i tried was:

**View:**

```
<script>
   @Session["TestingSession"]="Hello...";
</script>
```

but the value didn't go through to the action in the controller - there the value was null.

**Controller:**

```
var a=Session["TestingSession"];
```

any ideas?

Comment: `Session` is server side. Javascript is client side. You need to pass the value to the server (e.g. using ajax) and set it in the controller

Comment: ok. i dont really know how to use ajax. can you give me more specific directions? thanks

Comment: Then time for you to do some research :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is server side you would have to pass the variable to the server via ajax.

The easiest way (personal opinion) to conduct an ajax request is to use jQuery library.

This is how to do an ajax request in jQuery:

```
$(function () {

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST"
        ,data: {
            sessionVariable: variable
        }
        ,url: //enter the url of your controller/action which the session variable is being sent to, and handled by the server.
        ,success: function(returnedData){
            alert("Session successfully sent to the server");
            // you could return something from the controller with more info and display this using the returnedData object.
        }
        ,error: function(){
           alert("something went wrong");
        }
  });
})
```

for more info n jQuery ajax follow this link > http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){ 
  $.ajax({
    url     :'ajax page url',
    method  :'get/post',
    data     : variable containing data,
    success:function(html)
     {
       alert('success');
     }
  })
});
```

and than add values in session on the ajax page